# Angular 15 Cannot find module '@env/environment' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, typescript, relative-path

I have created a angular 15 application. My environments folder is under src.

Following is a snippet from my tsconfig.json:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
"@app/*": [
  "app/*"
],
"rxjs": [
  "./vendor/rxjs.ts"
],
"@env/*": [
  "environments/*"
]
}
```

But when I use relative path in my code (example in app.module .ts) I am getting error. I am using it as follows:

```
import { environment } from '@env/environment';
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the environment file is under the `src` folder. You need to specifiy it:

```
"@env/*": [
  "src/environments/*"
]
```

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't saw the base path. The `@env` part is correct, but:

You need to set this flag to true:

`"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

This is needed because it allows 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export.

Comment: I dont think that is a proper solution and it wont fix the issue. I have already mentioned  my baseUrl as "./src"

Comment: I've tried on a bran new project of mine and it works perfectly. Besides, this is the only soulition that allow you to import in such a way.  You may want to add the error is giving you.

Comment: The error is: Cannot find module '@env/environment' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Comment: You may need to adjust some config in the `ts config` file. Here the working demo: https://angular-gzz5rf.stackblitz.io

Comment: can you kindly suggest any of the configs you think that might help in this case ?

Comment: The stackblitz that you gave is keeping on loading....its not showing anything

Comment: just add "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true to your config. See the answer on why

Comment: That is absolutely the solution and no other answer has touched this option. You rock man. I am now reading through why and what is this option is all about.

Comment: Glad to have helped you out! You can find more details about that flag - and tsconfig in generale, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports)